# Connect to VPN ios8, persistent reference of password from keychain is null

Tags: objective-c, ios8, vpn, keychain

I am trying to connect vpn using NETWORK EXTENSION framework, but have some issue while get persistent reference of password stored in keychain. It [`NSLog(@"password: %@", [manager protocol].passwordReference);`] returns null after a call to `[manager saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {...}` but when I try to log before calling saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler it give me a valid reference in keychain. When I use this code block it gets all the details I have stored in keychain for persistent reference.

```
    NSDictionary *query = @{ (__bridge id)kSecValuePersistentRef: (__bridge NSData *)(KeychainUserPass.passwordPersistentReference),
                                 (__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes: (id)kCFBooleanTrue };

    CFDictionaryRef passwordDict = nil;
    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFTypeRef*)&passwordDict);
    NSLog(@"status: %ld, passwordDict: %@", status, (__bridge NSDictionary*)passwordDict);

    NSLog(@"keychain password: %@", p.passwordReference);
```

But why it does not get any detail when I use NEVPNManager class object to store password reference? and it prompts me to enter password whenever I tried to connect vpn instead of getting it from keychain?

Here is the code:

```
NEVPNProtocolIKEv2 *p = [[NEVPNProtocolIKEv2 alloc] init];
        p.username = @"username";
        p.passwordReference = (__bridge NSData *)(KeychainUserPass.passwordPersistentReference);

        p.serverAddress = @"hostname";
        p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethodCertificate;
        p.serverCertificateIssuerCommonName = @"Certificate Issuer name";
        p.serverCertificateCommonName = @"Certificate name";
        p.identityData = //p12;
        p.identityDataPassword = @"password for p12";
        p.localIdentifier = @"local identifier";
        p.remoteIdentifier = @"remote identifier";
        p.useExtendedAuthentication = YES;
        p.disconnectOnSleep = NO;
        [manager setProtocol:p];

        [manager setOnDemandEnabled:YES];

        [manager setLocalizedDescription:@"VPN Profile"];
        [manager saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if(error) {
                NSLog(@"Save error: %@", error);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Saved!");
                NSLog(@"OnDemandEnable: %d", [manager isOnDemandEnabled]);
                NSLog(@"onDemandRules: %@", [manager onDemandRules]);
                NSLog(@"username: %@", [manager protocol].username);
                NSLog(@"password: %@", [manager protocol].passwordReference);
            }
        }];
    }
```

P.S: Everything works fine except this issue.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue, on iOS 9 it works but on iOS 8 I get the same issue you described. Did you ever figure out the issue or it's just an iOS bug?

Comment: The only issue was in saving/retrieving the password from keychain. You may take [help from](http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/09/26/how-to-get-persistent-references-to-keychain-items-in-ios/) .. All you have to do is after getting data from keychain put your result set into dictionary and get your password reference using 'v_PersistentRef' key.

Comment: Hey can you please tell me how to add certificate for NEVPNProtocolIKEv2 protocol in bit brief ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the preferences before you can alter them. Make sure to run loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler and then create your protocol and make your updates.

Comment: Whenever I load profile from preferences and makes changes like change the host address and save it back to the preferences it lost the reference to the password.. Do you have any idea about it?